# AWS Network Load Balancers and Ephemeral ports

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, nlb

I have an AWS NLB listening on port 443 with TLS. The requests are forwarded to a TCP Taget Group, port 80. My app is containerized and deployed through ECS. I want to take advantage of the dynamic port mapping provided by ECS. Do I need to open the ephemeral ports in the ECS Container Instance Security Group? I find that if I do not explicitly open them, my Target Group cannot register the Instance. Though, the documentation and the tutorials don't seem to explicitly mention to open the ports... Thanks.

Comment: Agree absolutely! I'm looking for CDK examples with NLB and there are only basics, while ALB has a much more complex config.
https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cdk-examples/blob/master/typescript/ecs/ecs-service-with-advanced-alb-config/index.ts

Comment: I've opened an issue: https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cdk-examples/issues/446